# How to render json to jquery

Tags: jquery, json, grails

How can I render a `.json` file from the assets directory to a `jquery` script in `grails`? This is my jquery code where I want to render the json file:

```js
let dropdown = $('#banks');

dropdown.empty();

dropdown.append('<option selected="true" disabled>Select bank</option>');
dropdown.prop('selectedIndex', 0);

const url = '';

$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (key, entry){
        dropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', entry.abbreviation).text(entry,name))
    })
})
```

Comment: You have a typo: `entry,name` should be `entry.name`

Comment: You can simplify it to `$("<option>", {value: entry.abbreviation, text: entry.name})`

Answer (score 0):

in controller

```
import grails.converters.JSON
import asset//ur asset

class renderJsonController {

    def renderJson() {

        def result = asset.getJsonFromAsset()//Getter function in asset to get target json 

        render result as JSON
    }
}
```

in .gsp

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '${createLink(controller: 'renderJson', action: 'renderJson')}',
    data: {},
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (json) {
        //!!get json here!!
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        defaultAjaxError(xhr)
    },
});
```